# Error in default export React Native using CRNA/Expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

Now this might be sound silly question, but this happened to me twice. It was working before perfectly but after I renamed the file, it gives me error

```
Element type is invalid expected a string(for built-in components) or a 
class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to 
export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

Here's my structure.

```
* App.js
* src
  - screens
    - Main
      - index.js
      - Main.js
```

## index.js

```
import Main from './Main';
export default Main;
```

## Main.js

```
const Main = () => null;
export default Main;
```

## App.js

```
import Main from './src/screens/Main/index';
```

I am using latest version of CRNA & EXPO. I know it has nothing to do with it, but still.

Comment: Try returning blank View instead of null, like this `const Main = () => <View />`

Comment: Its not the issue. I am actually returning some markup. I just posted this as the simple version of my problem.

Comment: Also, if I `console.log(Main);`, I get `[Function Main]` which is correct but exporting it results in a problem. It was working alright till I renamed `Home` to `Main`

Comment: You possibly forget to restart Expo server.

Comment: Whoops, got the answer. It was an err on my side. I deleted a component & was importing it.

Comment: Nope, got the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was importing another property in `Main.js` which did not exist like -

```
import { DoesNotExist } from './src/components/index';
```

So that was giving the error.